# Site Links use same HTML but different data is requested, how best to handle?

Tags: angular

**I have a site nav that has multiple links that set a parameter for the data but use the same HTML view.**

*I can make a different component for each link, but I feel there must be a better option.

If I use a param, I can set each route to the same page but using a different param, such as view:all or view:draft.

The issue is ngOnInit() { } only runs once, when the route is subsequently changed the address updates but it doesn't trigger the function calls.*

Any suggestions for how to handle this vs multiple components?

Comment: Subscribe to the `paramMap` or the `queryParamMap` observable in your `ngOnInit` (depending on which you're using) and call your function from within the `subscribe` block.

Comment: That worked perfectly. If you put this as an answer I'll mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscribe to the `paramMap` or `queryParamMap` observable in your `ngOnInit` (depending on how you're passing the params) and call your function from within the `subscribe` block.

```js
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
        // Call function with params to update template
    });
}
```